# Store uploaded files carrierwave RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, upload, carrierwave

i am trying to upload a file with carrierwave in my rails app and currently this is my code:

Controller:

```
def fileSave    
    @code.store!(code)
end
```

View:

```
= form_for @code = Code.new(params[:code]), :as => :code, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

    div class="browse"
        span

        = f.file_field :code

        = f.submit 'Upload'
```

Uploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class CodeUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    def pre_limit file
        #require 'debugger'; debugger
        if file && file.size > 100.megabytes
            raise Exception.new('too large')
        end
        true
    end

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "public/uploads"
  end

    def extension_white_list
        %w(txt js ttf html)
    end

    def filename
        "file.txt" if original_filename
    end

end
```

Model:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

class Code < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :code
    mount_uploader :code, CodeUploader

end
```

And my problem is i can not store the uploaded file. x[ I am sure this is like 3 lines of code but i can not figure it out. Also the file to be uploaded is expected to be txt (probably figured that out looking the extension list).

Thanks to all readers and answerers. :}

P.S. I was wondering if i could create some kind of imaginary file, a file which is not really created. The is idea is if a take a text from a textarea and create a file (the imaginary one), store the text inside and then eventually save the whole file (maybe use carrierwave as and manually store it).

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: I am not getting an error, simply the file is not stored. :}

Comment: have you checked Rails logs, or the output at the terminal (if you're running webrick) for errors?

Comment: Yep, no errors. I can feel there is something wrong with the controller but i just do not know what has to be done there to make it work. ;[